# Is possible to access WCF Service without adding Service Reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I need to access Wcf service methods without adding Service Reference?how to do this?

Step 1:I create a WCF Service.
Step 2:Add Service Reference to my application.
Step 3:And Access the WCF Service methods into app.

like this way,

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDetails userInfo = new UserDetails();
    userInfo.UserName = TextBoxUserName.Text;
    userInfo.Password = TextBoxPassword.Text;
    userInfo.Country = TextBoxCountry.Text;
    userInfo.Email = TextBoxEmail.Text;
    string result = obj.InsertUserDetails(userInfo);
    LabelMessage.Text = result;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use as follows. Just make sure to add the Service contract reference.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4684/Service1.svc");
ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
ServiceContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
string resturnmessage = channel.YourMethod("test");
```

From [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/accessing-wcf-service-without-creating-proxy/) you can get fully workout regarding on that.

Comment: I think the third line should be ChannelFactory<ServiceContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);

Comment: using System.ServiceModel;

Comment: @Thilina H, in .NET 4.5, I'm getting red squiggly lines under "ServiceContract".  I fixed based on 1st comment, but still getting error.  It says "The type or namespace 'ServiceContract' could not be found" ... how do I reference the ServiceContract correctly to avoid that compile error?  What needs to be done in this project and/or the WCF Service project?

Comment: posted new question here with a little more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071525/consume-wcf-service-from-client-without-assembly-reference

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to invoke as WCF service without adding a service reference.

As a first step, I assume that you have your service contact interface as a separate class library.

Step 2: Create your WCF service and host it in IIS

Step 3: Refer your service contract library in the client application and then follow this code

```
ChannelFactory<IYourServiceContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IYourServiceContract>("EndpointNameOfYourService");
factory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/service");  

IYourServiceContract client = factory.CreateChannel();
var result = client.YourMethodtoInvoke(serviceArguments);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Risking the markdown lynch mob with this, but...

If the **reason** you're not adding the reference is because you need to choose the URL at runtime, you can still add the reference and then change it when you need to with:

```
MyProxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(MyUri);
```

(or do the same thing in the constructor when you instantiate).

Comment: This is assuming that both uri have the same "wsdl"... say, you have QA and PROD servers. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don`t have a reputation for commenting the answer of "Thilina H", but you can use code

```cs
ServiceContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

only if you wrote:

```cs
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
```

instead

```cs
ChannelFactoryfactory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
```

Answer (score 0):

When in John did this:
"Step 2:Add Service Reference to my application."
Visual Studio added the endpoint and default bindings to the app.config file of his application.  He does not need to specify a URL.  John's code should work just fine as long as the service has implemented the required contracts.