# Consume WCF service from client without WCF Service Library project/assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicecontract

The following question may be a duplicate, but there wasn't enough information to answer my question from it.

[Is possible to access WCF Service without adding Service Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675194/is-possible-to-access-wcf-service-without-adding-service-reference)

I've setup a TCP service, using a WCF Service Library project in Visual Studio by following this guide.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

This worked wonderful if you add a reference to the WCF Service Library project from your client (Windows Forms project).  And add a using statement to the project assembly and use this code.

```
        TcpService.Service myService = new TcpService.Service();
        myService.GetData(123);
```

> However, I don't want to add a reference to the TcpService assembly in
>   the project calling the method "GetData".  Per the very first
>   question's answer above.

So I tried using this code.  I added a reference to System.ServiceModel (and a using directive) to resolve most of the errors.  But now it says "The type or namespace name 'ServiceContract' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  Do I need to modify the App.Config in my service, or add any other code (with regard to 'ServiceContract') to the project calling this code below?

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service");
        ChannelFactory<ServiceContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
        ServiceContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        channel.GetData(123);
```

[image]

Note: I renamed the default Service1.cs and the default interface IService1.cs to Service.cs and IService.cs.  Without the "1" as the suffix, based on the instructions.  I also renamed WcfServiceLibrary1 to TcpService in my code.  Also, in .NET 4.5, I didn't need this line of code at all for it to work.  This .Close() errored out.

```
myService.Close();
```

I added a Service Reference in Visual Studio, by right clicking the Project > Add > Service Reference.  But I get an error there.

[image]

Error in 2nd dialog:

> The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service'. Could not
>   connect to net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service. The connection attempt
>   lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0011001. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:8523.  No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523 If the service is defined
>   in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide was missing a step.  I set the `httpsGetEnabled` to "false" in addition to the `httpGetEnabled` attribute, and it worked!  After that, I was no longer getting the error when adding a Service Reference.  And then I changed the 'ServiceContract' to 'MyClientProject.ServiceReference1.IService' to be refer to the new Service Reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

...

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```