# WCF defines it's own version of a DataObject in the Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, idataobject

I’ve created an object that I would like to pass in a WCF call… but inside ServiceReference1… this object is redefined… is there a way to just use the original object everywhere… it seems like people have done this but I can’t figure out what I am doing wrong.

The object is used as a parameter to a function in the service contract.

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UpdateInformation(MyObject myObject);
```

The error that I get when I try to call the function from my client is “Argument 1: cannot convert from ‘MyNameSpaceDTO.MyObject' to ‘MyNameSpace.ServiceReference1.MyObject’”

The object is in it’s own class library dll and it is marked with [DataObject] and [DataMember] attributes.

```
namespace MyNameSpaceDTO
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    ….
```

But, also ends up in Reference.cs after adding the Service Reference as:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyObject", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNameSpaceDTO")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class MyObject : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string NameField;
    ...
```

Also, I **do** have the following set in the Advanced section of the Add Service Reference:

[x] Reuse types in referenced assemblies

(o) Reuse types in all referenced assemblies

Comment: How does your solution structure look like? I guess there are several assemblies: A contract-assembly which holds the DTOs, another assembly which hosts the service and a third which acts as a client to that service?

Comment: I have one for the DTO... a library that contains both the client and the service code... and then two WinForms apps one that instantiates and uses the client functions and the other that instantiates and uses the service functions.

Comment: Ok, and in the client-app you referenced the service via the _Add service reference_ dialogue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consuming a WCF service you often see samples (and they're undoubtedly advisable!) where you're instructed to add that service via the *Add Service Reference* dialog. By referencing a service that way your client application creates proxy classes form the WSDL exposed by the service.

As a result you end up having e.g. a class `MyNameSpaceDTO.MyObject` in your contract-assembly and a `MyNameSpace.ServiceReference1.MyObject` in your client application which was generated form the WSDL. This may *seem* somewhat redundant.

One situation in which you may need this behaviour could be the following: Imagine you'd want to consume an arbitrary public web service which you don't control. You have no access to the contract-assembly which defines the types etc. In that situation creating your own local proxy classes from the exposed WSDL is optimal since it's your only way to get the needed types and so on.

But your concrete situation seems to be a little bit different. I think what you're looking for is a **shared contract**. Since you're in control of the client *and* server code (and both live happily side by side in the same solution), you're in the comfortable situation to just *share* the contract:

So instead of adding a service reference within your client-app (via *Add Service Reference*), you'd just reference the contract-assembly (via the usual *Add Reference* dialogue). By doing this there'll by only one `MyNameSpaceDTO.MyObject` since the second one is never created and not needed. This approach is called contract sharing.

Please take a look at that example:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Please note some changes: The most important one is that you usually wouldn't want to share the assembly which holds your implementation logic of your service. So I extracted that part from the Contract-assembly and put it in a separate Implementation-assembly. By doing so, you simply share the interfaces and types and not the implementation logic. This change is reflected in the screenshot above, too.

You could set up that small solution with the following classes:

Contract - `IService1.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

Implementation - `Service1.cs`:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Host - `Program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Service1/");

        using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress))
        {
            // Enable metadata publishing.
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since no endpoints are
            // explicitly configured, the runtime will create one endpoint per base address
            // for each service contract implemented by the service.
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client - `Program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to proceed.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Service1/");
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint);

        // Create a channel.
        IService1 wcfClient1 = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        string s = wcfClient1.GetData(42);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        ((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to quit the client.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "Please take a look at that example"... which example?

Comment: I meant that screenshot which (hopefully) visually explains what I wrote.

Comment: Ok... got it... sorry if I am being dense... but now... there is not a ServiceReference1 (since I don't run Add Service Reference)... so how do I call the service code from my client?

Comment: This looks like it addresses how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675194/is-possible-to-access-wcf-service-without-adding-service-reference

Comment: Yes, you could do it like that.

Comment: This link was even better: http://realfiction.net/2008/01/30/The-no-frills-bare-bones-example-to-Duplex-WCF/